# Firebird version check, any ideas?

Tags: windows, firebird

My application uses Firebird 2.5 and the installer needs to check whether any previous version of Firebird is installed on the system.

Earlier I was checking particularly version 2.0.1 by registry methods, but now I need to check for any version.

I have found some service API to retrieve version no, but that requires writing a small c/c++ program. I'm looking for some registry / other methods. Any clues ?

Comment: I don't think you can reliably detect that. I have three Firebird versions on my computer and none of them have a registry entry

Comment: Assuming you want to check installed versions (and not manually deployed zip kits), then you can query the list of installed applications. I believe most installer tools have support for that (but as I never write installers for Windows software, I am not sure, nor do I know exactly how).

Comment: Well, per my knowledge installed program are listed under registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall". And I can enumerate through them and search for 'Firebird' keyword there. But then afterwards I need to uninstall the service and install my own. I'm thinking to check for firebird service using 'sc qc' and then delete the existing service before installing my one.

Comment: @hypheni Most users don't appreciate it if you go and remove software they installed (and configured). If you need a specific Firebird service for your application, then either configure it on a non-default port with a non-default service name, or make your application use Firebird embedded.

Answer (score -1):

Go to:
Control Panel -> Programs 
You will see Firebird with version number installed